# the geometric realization of a simplicial set is contractible

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, fibration, classifying-spaces

Let $M$ be a monoid up to homotopy. The simplicial set $WM$ is defined by setting 
$$
WM_n=M^{n+1}=\{(g_0, g_1,\cdots,g_n)\mid g_i\in M\}
$$
with faces and degeneracies given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
d_i(g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n)&=&
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcl}
   (g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_{i-1},g_ig_{i+1},g_{i+2},\cdots,g_n)& \text{if} & i<n, \\
 (g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_{n-1})& \text{if} & i=n;
\end{array}
\right.\\
s_i(g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n)&=&(g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_i,e,g_{i+1},\cdots,g_n).
\end{eqnarray*}
Define the left action of $M$ on $M^{n+1}$ by setting 
$$
g\cdot (g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n)=(gg_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n).
$$
Then $d_i(g\cdot (g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n))=g\cdot d_i (g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n)$ and $s_ig\cdot (g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n)=g \cdot s_i (g_0,g_1,\cdots,g_n)$, that is, the action
$$
M\times WM\to WM
$$
is simplicial. By modolo the action of $M$, we obtain the simplicial set 
$$
\bar WM=WM/M.$$

The standart geometric $n$-simplex is the space
$$
\Delta^n=\{(t_0,t_1,\cdots,t_n)\mid t_i\geq 0 and \sum_{i=0}^n t_i=1\}.
$$
Define $d^i: \Delta^{n-1}\to \Delta^n$ and $s^i: \Delta^{n+1}\to \Delta^n$ by setting 
\begin{eqnarray*}
d^i(t_0,t_1,\cdots, t_{n-1})&=&(t_0, \cdots, t_{i-1},0,t_i,\cdots, t_{n-1}),\\
s^i(t_0,t_1,\cdots, t_{n+1})&=&(t_0, \cdots, t_{i-1},t_i+t_{i+1},\cdots, t_{n+1})
\end{eqnarray*}
for $0\leq i\leq n$.  For a simplicial set $X$, the geometric realization $|X|$ is a CW-complex defined by
\begin{eqnarray*}
|X|&=&\bigsqcup_{x\in X_n,n\geq 0}(\Delta^n,x)/\sim\\
&=&\bigsqcup_{n=0}^\infty \Delta^n\times X_n/\sim
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\sim$ is generated by 
$$
(z,d_ix)\sim (d^iz,x)
$$ 
for any $x\in X_n$ and $z\in \Delta^{n-1}$, and
$$
(z,s_ix)\sim(s^iz,x)
$$
for any $x\in X_n$ and $z\in \Delta^{n+1}$.

For a monoid up to homotopy $M$, we denote the geometric realization of $WM$  by $EM$ and the geometric realization of $\bar WM$  by $BM$. The CW-complex $BM$ is called the classifying space of $M$.

My question:

**Conjecture: 
(1). There is a canonical map $p: EM\to BM$ such that for any $b\in BM$, the preimage $p^{-1}(M)$ is homeomorphic to $M$. 
(2). Moreover, $EM$ is contractible.**

**How to prove the conjecture? Any references for the proof?  Thanks for giving help! If my construction of the classifying space $BM$ and the "universal map" $EM\to BM$ is wrong, where can I find the correct construction?**

Comment: What exactly is the quotient of a set by an action of a monoid?

Comment: Independently of that, your WM does not seem to depend on the topology of M.

Comment: If the monoid is only associative up to homotopy, then your face maps do not satisfy the simplicial identities, by the way.